# Build Loki dashboard for logs count

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to build Grafana dashboard representing the number of info logs in Loki (not in Prometheus). Basically, I would like to achieve this:

[image]

I searched around and it seems it is possible to build those with Prometheus metrics, using the `logback_events` metrics from Prometheus.

Actually, the dashboard above is using Prometheus data, using the `logback_events` not Loki data.

However my application is not sending any metrics, just logs to Loki. Therefore, I cannot rely on metrics of type `logback_events` to build this dashboard.

Where a sample log looks like:

```
{
"name": "mycoolapp"
"pid": "1",
"level": "INFO",
"thread": "somethread",
"class": "SomeClass",
"traceId": "6170ea9877f59d050a13feaffc145d88"
"spanId": "6729eec142171c8f"
"message": "somecoolmessage"
}
```

Is there a way to get the number of info, error, warn, and debug logs from Loki? How to build a similar dashboard using Loki (not Prometheus) data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With query like this, you can create graph for number of log entries per level.

```
sum by(level)(
 count_over_time( 
  {<your_usual_stream_selector>}
  | json 
  [$__interval]
 )
)
```

If you need only number of messages with level `INFO` you can add filter after `| json`, like this: `| json | level = "INFO"`.

Please notice, that here `{<your_usual_stream_selector>}` is a placeholder for your actual stream selector. It depends on your setup and dashboard configuration. In the simplest case it might be something like `{host="example.com"}` or `{filename="log.json"}`.

Comment: Looking forward to these fire edits, not convinced by this "do absolutely nothing at all but complain at people who _aren't_ the OP" approach https://stackoverflow.com/q/77733046/3001761